# How to find the most common name in file?

Tags: bash, awk, zsh

I have file with content (5 columns):

```
text1:##text1:27438:1001:Name Surname Role:
text1:##text1:27438:1001:Name2 Surname Role:
text1:##text1:27438:1001:Name3 Surname Role:
text1:##text1:27438:1001:Name4 Surname Role:
......
+10000 lines
```

and I want to find the most common Name.

What I tried is:

```
cat /opt/users | awk '{print $5}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n | tail -1
```

but I'm getting a numeric value.

Have I made a mistake here?

```
awk '{print $5}'
```

What command can I try next?

Comment: ```awk -F: '{print $5}' /opt/users |...```

Comment: Without setting the field separator as @vgersh99 showed, your `$1` is `text1:##text1:27438:1001:Name` and `$2` is `Surname` ...

Comment: awk uses spaces as the default seperator. The $5 column (by spaces) is empty - hence the result is just a number, or more specifically: empty string, number of lines

Comment: How should awk determine the field separator? It could be `#` or `:` or anything else. By default it is white space.

Comment: When you say "I want to find the most common Name", do you mean the full value of the 5th field ("I have 5 John Smiths") or part of the 5th field ("I have 10 Smiths")?

Comment: This comes to mind: [Falsehoods programmers believe about names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Comment: @glennjackman *lol* - I haven't read that before! Great! "_People’s names are all mapped in Unicode code points._" - I wonder if _The artist formerly known as Prince_ got a code point before he switched back to _Prince_? The last one is the winner: "40. People have names" :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you need to add `:` as a field separator. Space is the default separator and if you use that, the fields get assigned like this:

```
$1 = text1:##text1:27438:1001:Name
$2 = Surname 
$3 = Role:
```

Also, let `awk` open and read from the file directly.

Here, both `:` and *space* serve as field separators:

```
awk -F'[: ]' '{print $5}' /opt/users | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | head -1
```

Assigning the fields then becomes:

```
$1 = text1
$2 = ##text1
$3 = 27438
$4 = 1001
$5 = Name
$6 = Surname 
$7 = Role
$8 =        (empty)
```

Note: You also have the built-in variable `NF` that will tell you the `N`umber of `F`ields that got assigned per line. `8` in the case above.

Comment: omg thank u that's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

With GNU awk, you don't need other tools. Pending the answer to my comment above:

```sh
gawk -F: '
    {count[$5]++}
    END {
        PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_desc"
        for (name in count) {
            print count[name], name
            exit
        }
    }
' file
```

To find the most common *word* in the name field

```
    # replace `{count[$5]++}` with
    {
        n = split($5, names, /[[:blank:]]+/)
        for (i=1; i<=n; i++) count[names[i]]++
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Filter out empty lines and also sort in reverse order (sort -nr):

```
grep -v -e "^$" /opt/users | cut -f5 -d: | \
  cut -f1 -d" " | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | tail -1
```

As already mentioned, `awk` uses a space/tab characters as a default field separator (-F option).

Comment: thank you for your help! however I had to select previous answer as solution and use it in my task due it is shorter: awk -F'[: ]' '{print $5}' /opt/users | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | head -1